# Configuring Kdevelop for Python 3

Tags: python3, kdevelop

I've installed kdevelop 4.7.1 & kde-python 1.7.1
The default configuration is using Python 2 in the code autocompletion & the console. How do I set things up for Python 3?

Also, code autocompletion, from my so far brief look, seems patchy: It will find functions on strings, eg 'hi there!'.uppercase(), but won't autocomplete on imported modules: eg re.compile() or os.getcwd(). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate package for the Python 3 version of the python plugin. If your distribution does not ship it, please complain.

Code completion in Python is unfortunately very hard for some of the shipped modules. Look at os.py -- there's no way to find e.g. the declaration of getcwd() there :/
The re module should work ok though, eventually you have to wait a moment for the background parser to finish analyzing after adding the import.
Completion will work much better for code you write yourself, which is usually the more important part in practice.